# Netatalk -- should every client connect through a separate account?

Tags: network-share, ubuntu-14.04, bonjour, netatalk

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 server running Netatalk 3.1.7. It's serving files to 3-4 other computers running a mixture of OSX Yosemite and Windows 7 (the latter connects via Samba rather than Netatalk).

My question is should all of these machines be authenticating via separate user accounts, or is it okay for them to connect using the same credentials? Currently I have a single account (files) which they all use, but I'm trying to diagnose some minor performance issues and I wondered if separating out the accounts per client machine might help this, or whether that's good practice anyway.

It's a simple question but one which I haven't been able to find an answer to!

Answer (score 0):

There won't be a performance impact either way. Having different accounts primarily allows for more granular permissions and it's up to you to decide of you need those.

If you don't, just keeping everything with the same account will make things easier to configure, so I would keep it that way.